# Is it legal to copy stats and abilities of characters from another game?

Tags: copyright

Is it legal to copy stats and abilities of characters from another game?.Please note that my game does have a similar gameplay to the game I am copying. My characters will look different of course.

Comment: Please note that "Not being illegal to do so" does not mean "You won't get sued for it".

Comment: If I recall correctly, I think [the copying of prices and hierarchies from Triple Town was one of the details cited in an infringement case against Yeti Town](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/178154/There_is_substantial_similarity_between_Triple_Town_and_Yeti_Town__US_court.php#.UGHYolGenIM), which ultimately resulted in a settlement where Yeti Town's copyright was transferred to Triple Town's developer. Basically, every similarly your game has can be one more point of ammunition against you in an infringement case. Better to make your own original games than chance a costly lawsuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I am not a lawyer* so keep in mind that *what I will write is just what I remember* from different articles I've read before.

**In short:** 
If you copy only the gameplay part (stat and way of playing) and nothing else, then it should be ok (I repeat double check that. I am not a lawyer)

**More details:**
If I remember well, in the law point of view, video games are not considered as a whole, but as many parts (music, design, art, animation, etc.) and each part is protected by its own law. The only thing that cannot be copyrighted is the gameplay which include abilities and stats. That's why there is a lot of game being part of the same style of gameplay without problem. But keep in mind that many other details can be protected. For example I think that the name of the ability and the animation when using it can be copyrighted.

Hope it will help you but wait for the answer of someone who truly know the law because I am just repeating things I've heard.

Comment: Some links which give you much more details  : http://newmediarights.org/guide/legal/Video_Games_law_Copyright_Trademark_Intellectual_Property#What%20parts%20of%20the%20video%20game%20are%20copyrightable?
http://www.gbgames.com/articles/indie-legal-copyright-and-trademark/what-an-indie-needs-to-know-about-copyright/

Comment: @user98577 You're welcome ;) and gl for making your game !